# C# httpwebrequest Keep Alive

Tags: c#, http

Связь с сервером происходит через Keep Alive, используя httpwebrequest. При посылке запроса приходит ответ от сервера, что запрос верный, а потом в этом же соединении сервер начинает передавать нужные данные. Не могу получить эти нужные данные, только самый первый ответ о верных данных, хотя в заголовке запроса на сервер указано, что это Keep Alive.

Comment: так java или c# ?